# Open Visual Studio Dev prompt and enter sequence of commands

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, cmd, command, prompt

I want to use PowerShell to run a script that:

1. Launches Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt (VS 2017)
2. Enters in sequence of commands to do a batch and release build

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" && <next sequence of commands to do batch build>
```

The above code simultaneously opens VS Dev prompt and my sequence of commands. There is no pause after opening the prompt, so the commands do not run.

[Screenshot of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odw1E.png)

Comment: Please try this: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K "Call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" && <next sequence of commands to do batch build>"```

Comment: Thanks @compo, that returns a 'system cannot find the path specified' error. I tried adding Visual Studio and the VsDevCmd to the path in environment variables, but that didn't resolve it. :-?

Comment: The only way what I posted would give that error, is if you posted the wrong path, or if your deadly secret `<next sequence of commands to do batch build>` string contains one. Either way, neither of those can be considered as my error.

Comment: This syntax worked as desired: 

cmd /c 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe' '<VS2019.sln file>' /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32 /flp:LogFile="<output directory for build logs>"